# Dependency links for extras_require in setup.py

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py

1. Is there a way to process dependency links automatically when installing a package with extras, without having to call `--process-dependency-links` as it is the case with `install_requires`?

   ```
   pip install -e .[extra] --process-dependency-links
   ```

   I need this because the dependency is only located on a private git repo.
2. Is it possible to install extras using `python setup.py install`?
3. Is `--process-dependency-links` still to be considered as it is deprecated? I am not sure about the status here.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @chishaku not really... But with all that's currently happening with pyproj.toml, and the new pip, we might have some luck!

Comment: I think I did, actually.  Will add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you no longer need `--process-dependency-links` if you use `extras_require`.

Tested with pip version 19.3.1

Example:

```py
$ pip install -e .[graphs]

# setup.py  

from setuptools import setup
setup(
    name='myservice',
    version='0.1.0',
    install_requires=[
        'requests',
    ],
    extras_require={
        'graphs': [
            'graphcommons @ git+ssh://git@github.com/graphcommons/graphcommons-python@master',
        ],
    },
)
```

By using ssh protocol (instead of https) to access git repo, you can install from your private repos.

2. Not sure about `python setup.py install` but `pip install .[extras]` should be good enough?
3. Yes, in pip version 19.

Answer (score 6):

I searched way too long to figure out how to do this with setup.cfg so hopefully this will help someone else if they don't want to use setup.py as the OP didn't specify. I've also included a custom URL for install_requires as that took a while to figure out as well.

```
#setup.cfg (only showing relevant parts)
[options]
install_requires =
    pyyaml @ git+https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml.git@master
    
[options.extras_require]
jsonschema = jsonschema @ git+https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema.git@v3.2.0
six = six
```

1. `pip install -e .[jsonschema]` will get you the extra with a custom URL or `pip install -e .[jsonschema,six]` will get you both extras (note that there are NO spaces after the `.` or around the comma(s) in the extras list).
2. As far as I can tell, you cannot get extras installed using `python setup.py install`.
3. Yes `--process-dependency-links` is still deprecated in spite of much complaining but the above is good enough once you know the syntax.